# CSS loading after html rendered Angular 4 and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I am unable to identify, why html is loaded and css loads after afterwards, making the page look weird at first. Following is my conf files:

**webpack.conf.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'tslint'
            }
        ],

        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.json$/,
                loaders: [
                    'json'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['css-loader?sourceMap']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                loaders: ['css-loader?sourceMap', 'resolve-url', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'url',
                query: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    minetype: 'application/font-woff'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|jpg|png|gif)$/,
                loader: 'url',
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [
                    'ts'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /index\.html$/,
                loader: [
                    'html'
                ]
            }
        ],
        noParse: [ /zone\.js\/dist\/.+/, /angular2\/bundles\/.+/ ]
    },
    plugins: [
        //https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/993 fixes typescript warning
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            __dirname
        ),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: `${conf.path.src('index.html')}`,
            inject: true,
            appD: conf.getAppDID()
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(conf.environment),
                'root': JSON.stringify(conf.paths.root)
            }
        })
    ],
    postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '',
            '.webpack.js',
            '.web.js',
            '.js',
            '.ts'
        ]
    },
    entry: [
        `bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader?configFilePath=../../../.bootstraprc!bootstrap-loader/no-op.js`,
        `./${conf.path.src('polyfills')}`,
        `./${conf.path.src('vendor')}`,
        `./${conf.path.src('index')}`
    ],
    ts: {
        configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
    },
    tslint: {
        configuration: require('../tslint.json')
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
 {
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/common": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/core": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/forms": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/http": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.5",
        "@angular/router": "4.3.5",
        "@stomp/ng2-stompjs": "0.4.1",
        "angular2-moment": "1.6.0",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "lodash": "4.17.4",
        "net": "1.0.2",
        "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
        "primeng": "4.1.2",
        "quill": "1.2.6",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
        "rxjs": "5.4.2",
        "uuid": "3.1.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.5",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.3",
        "@types/core-js": "^0.9.42",
        "@types/debug": "^0.0.29",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.53",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.73",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.14",
        "@types/sinon": "^2.3.3",
        "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.29",
        "@types/webpack": "^2.2.16",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "argv": "^0.0.2",
        "async": "^2.5.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
        "bootstrap-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
        "electron": "^1.6.11",
        "eslint": "^2.11.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
        "fail-on-errors-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
        "gulp": "gulpjs/gulp#4ed9a4a3275559c73a396eff7e1fde3824951ebb",
        "gulp-cheerio": "^0.6.2",
        "gulp-modify-file": "^0.1.0",
        "gulp-remove-empty-lines": "^0.1.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
        "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
        "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
        "intl": "^1.2.5",
        "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
        "karma": "^1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
        "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
        "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
        "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
        "karma-source-map-support": "^1.2.0",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
        "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
        "mime": "1.3.6",
        "ng2-popover": "0.0.13",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
        "pretty-data": "^0.40.0",
        "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.10.0",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "sass-resources-loader": "^1.3.0",
        "sinon": "^2.3.8",
        "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
        "tslint": "^5.6.0",
        "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
        "tslint-microsoft-contrib": "^5.0.1",
        "typescript": "^2.4.2",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
        "wallaby-webpack": "^0.0.38",
        "webpack": "2.5.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.8.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
        "yargs": "^8.0.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "npm-run-all --parallel clean:*",
        "clean:coverage": "rimraf coverage",
        "clean:dist": "rimraf dist",
        "clean:npm": "rimraf node_modules",
        "clean:tmp": "rimraf .tmp",
        "build": "webpack --config conf/webpack.config.js",
        "build:dist": "npm run build -- --env.serve=dist",
        "build:dist:prod": "npm run build:dist -- --env.node=production",
        "i18n:extract": "ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xlf -p tsconfig-i18n.json",
        "lint": "tslint --type-check --project tsconfig.json",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config conf/webpack.config.js",
        "start:dist": "npm start -- --env.serve=dist",
        "start:dist:prod": "npm run start:dist -- --env.node=production",
        "test": "karma start conf/karma.conf.js --single-run",
        "test:auto": "npm test -- --no-single-run"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "jasmine": true
        }
    }
}
```

What is required to done in this case? Do I need to change anything in webpack.conf file or would require any package for that purpose.

Comment: Does this only happen when deploying for production? Did you test your applicating using basic webpack developement server?(npm start)

Comment: this is happening on my local machine and development, since this is not deployed to production yet, so I am not sure about production

Comment: @SahilAgarwal were you able to solve the issue ?